# Changing Python interpreter in PyCharm from the command line

Tags: pycharm

I can successfully change Python interpreter or virtualenv from the PyCharm GUI.

Is it possible to update Python interpreter (or virtualenv) from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean change the venv of the current terminal session, there's `workon py3` and `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`.

If you mean changing the executing venv of pycharm from the command line though, you could probably mangle together a couple symlinking functions that just changes which venv a linked directory is pointing at.

Comment: I mean changing the executing venv of PyCharm. If you have a specific suggestion I'd like to know. Thanks.

Comment: if venvs work the way I believe they do, you can have pycharm point at a symlink called `pycharm_venv` or whatever you want to call that and have that pointed at which ever venv you want to be using. then when you want to change the venv for pycharm, you just redirect the symlink.

Comment: My issue is with the initial setup of the venv in PyCharm. I want to do it with the command line and not with the GUI. If I'll have that, then changing venvs afterwards won't be a problem.